# pfsense facing problems in setting up wan and lan interface

Tags: pfsense

I need to configure pfsense wan and lan interface in the virtualbox

the network diagram is like ISP ----> cisco modem --> ip:192.168.1.1 ( NAT & DHCP configured (ranges from 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.149) ---> centos 6.6 (Host Machine getting ip address through dhcp) --> pfsense (installed in virtualbox 5.0 )

After finishing the installation and assigning interfaces, the wan ip: 0.0.0.0 and lan ip: 192.168.1.1 which is my cisco modem ip (is a gateway).

wan interface is configured as bridged adapter and lan interface is configured as internal network adapter. I also tested by configuring lan interface as bridged adapter.

Note: Suggestion without enabling bridged mode in cisco modem will be very helpful for me since, i am in a testing environment.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to make the pfSense VM the router for your physical network?

Comment: no only for all guest machines in the virtualbox and i can't even ping the lan ip of pfsense from host machine

Comment: Do you have multiple network connections configured in your VM?  What type of connections (Bridged/NAT/Host Only/Internal) do each of the connections have?

Comment: the other guest machines in virtualbox is in internal network only.  The primary thing i need is to setup my pfsense machine so that i can configure rest of the things through web interface from host machine

Comment: Your pfSense VM needs both a Bridged network connection and an Internal network connection.  Is your pfSense VM configured that way?

Comment: yes i configured in that way only

Comment: So WAN should be your Bridged adapter, LAN is your internal.  What problems are  you having after that?

Comment: yes the problem is when i finish the setting up interface configuration the wan ip is 0.0.0.0 and lan ip is 192.168.1.1 but the lan ip is same as my gateway ip ie., cisco modem ip which is doing NAT and dhcp for our network.  i also changed the ip address for lan but that ip is not pinging from my host machine

Comment: You can change the LAN IP range in the pfSense configuration.

Comment: how to do that i don't know, please help me

Comment: Using "set interface ip address" option in pfsense i changed the lan ip address and still i can't ping or launch through web interface from the host machine

Comment: Is the LAN network working?   You should be able to access the pfSense web interface from the other VM on the internal network.

Comment: actually i installed centos 7 server without GUI.  so i can't do in that and also i don't have enough RAM to install another machine with GUI